# How to ask Cocoa app to run an action from the terminal and then return the result

Tags: bash, macos, cocoa, xpc

My Cocoa MacOS app has an action that modifies some files in the disk.
I want to make that actions available to run from a terminal.

For example, if I run:

```
$ echo `myApp runAction`
```

that would open the app, execute some code associated with "runAction", and then print a result to the console.

Unfortunately, I can't just make a Command Line Tool because of its limitations (can't include dynamic frameworks).

Any tips how to make it?

Answer (score 3):

You should make your app scriptable with Apple Script. With this you "speak" to your app in bash (or zsh) no matter if it is running or not by :

osascript -e 'tell app "myApp" to runAction'

or by an AppleScript script written in the Script Editor app.

When app is not running it will launch first.

There are a few examples/documentations in the web which are sufficient for basic tasks like executing a command and returning the result:

[Mac Scripter link](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=44750)

[Making A Mac App Scriptable Tutorial (raywenderlich.com) link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1033-making-a-mac-app-scriptable-tutorial)

In my case these docs were not sufficient for complicated tasks like passing parameters to the command, but for simple tasks like:

osascript -e 'tell app "myApp" to login'

osascript -e 'tell app "myApp" to logout'

— and myApp returns a literal "0" or "1" if the action failed for some reason or was successful —

it worked.
And osascript -e 'tell app "myApp" to quit' even came for free.

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Thanks Robert, I didn’t know about Apple Script. I wonder if this is the only way though. Is XPS Service another way this could be achieved?

Comment: With XPC you would need to write a command line client which sends commands by xpc to your app. But when the app is not running the client would fail. And the client has to be in the PATH to be useful in bash (or you bundle the client in the application bundle and you use an absolute path to that binary.

All in all it is more work to write the helper client. Just my 2 cts.

Comment: Robert, I tried to add basic scripting to my app. It works as expected so thank you. One thing that bothers me is that the first time I try to run the script, MacOS prompts me with the alert to grant "app X to control app Y". When I click "Don't allow", the only way to reenable it is to go to system Preferences app - kinda meh. Is there really no other way this could be done?

Comment: sorry, no - this is a security feature of macOS. Once you allow your script to control you app, you will never get bothered again.

Comment: The only way to undo your decision (and to get the dialog back) is to reset this decision for all applications.There is a cli command for that which I don't remember since I have never used that.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your application is an .app bundle, its executable is still the same kind of binary file that you would get in a Command Line Tool.

You can execute it in Terminal, pass arguments, print output. E.g.

> $ ./MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication --some-argument

Depending on what your app is for, it might be not perfect solution, but it’s a completely valid way to use it.

Comment: That's interesting. But is there a way to return some value in such approach? Plus I'd want the command line to wait until my app finishes the task.

Comment: @msmialko if you were going to make a command line utility, just treat the app bundle in the same way. I.e. use `print` to output text or use `exit` to return an exit code when the task is done.